# Parsing multi line comments from js using python

Tags: python, regex

I want to get the contents of the multiline comments in a js file using python.

I tried this code sample

```
import re
code_m = """
/* This is a comment. */
"""
code_s = "/* This is a comment*/"

reg = re.compile("/\*(?P<contents>.*)\*/", re.DOTALL + re.M) 
matches_m = reg.match(code_m)
matches_s = reg.match(code_s)
print matches_s # Give a match object
print matches_m # Gives None
```

I get `matches_m` as `None`. But `matches_s` works. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`match()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match) only matches at the start of the string, use [`search()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search) instead.

When using `match()`, it is like there is an implicit beginning of string anchor (`\A`) at the start of your regex.

As a side note, you don't need the `re.M` flag unless you are using `^` or `$` in your regex and want them to match at the beginning and end of lines.  You should also use a bitwise OR (`re.S | re.M` for example) instead of adding when combining multiple flags.

Comment: I have another question. Can you please help with it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144883/parse-multiple-comments-from-js-file-using-python

Answer (score 2):

`re.match` tests to see if the string matches the regex. You're probably looking for `re.search`:

```
>>> reg.search(code_m)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f293e94d648>
>>> reg.search(code_m).groups()
(' This is a comment. ',)
```