# Parse multiple comments from js file using python

Tags: javascript, python, regex, comments

I want to get contents of a js file comments. I tried using the code

```
import re
code = """
/*
This is a comment.
*/

/*
This is another comment.
*/

"""
reg = re.compile("/\*(?P<contents>.*)\*/", re.DOTALL)
matches = reg.search(code)

if matches:
    print matches.group("contents")
```

The result I get is

```
This is a comment.
*/

/*
This is another comment.
```

How can I get the comments separately ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the repetition ungreedy:

```
"/\*(?P<contents>.*?)\*/"
```

Now the `.*` will consume as little as possible instead of as much as possible.

To get multiple matches you will want to use [`findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) instead of `search`.

Comment: It only gave me first comment. How can I get both the comments ? Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Use [`findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) instead of `search`.

Comment: Will that handle embedded comments?

Comment: @grieve sorry, but what are embedded comments?

Comment: /* here is /* an embedded comment */ Well how about that! */

Comment: @grieve No it won't. Which is why regular expressions are not generally powerful enough to parse programming languages.

Comment: @grieve What you have given is not a valid comment. It will only produce error.

Comment: @MuhammedKK that's right in fact, because the first `*/` will end the comment. this is also what the regex would return

Comment: @grieve no it would really not work (well okay, I don't know about python, but most languages will end the comment at the first `*/`)